# Scala and Java Generics - Type Mismatch Error

Tags: scala, generics, scala-generics

There is a method with this signature:

```
public List<? extends TagNode> getElementListByName(String findName, boolean isRecursive) {
        return getElementList(new TagNodeNameCondition(findName), isRecursive);
}
```

In Scala I used the method like so:

```
val anchorNodes = bodyNode.getElementListByName("a", true)
```

and wrote a function to filter out all of the anchor tags with this signature:

```
def buildArticleLinksList(anchorTags: List[TagNode]): List[TagNode] = {
        @tailrec def buildArticlesList(articleLinksList: List[TagNode], anchorTags: List[TagNode]): List[TagNode] = anchorTags match {
            case Nil => articleLinksList
            case anchorTag :: tail if(anchorTag.getAttributeByName("href").contains(relativeCheckStr)) => buildArticlesList(articleLinksList:::List(anchorTag), tail)
        }

        buildArticlesList(List(), anchorTags)
}
```

but I get an error that says the following:

```
Type mismatch, expected: List[TagNode], actual: List[_ <: TagNode]
```

Could someone explain a way for me to declare my function that allows for type I am actually passing in please, it is a little confusing.

Comment: Declare it as the error message suggests perhaps? `List[_ <: TagNode]`

Comment: I did...but it said the same thing.

Comment: It said "expected List[TagNode]", when you declared it as `List[_ <: TagNode]`? Are you sure? Can you show the code?

Comment: no, it said: expected: List[_ <: TagNode], actual: List[_ <: TagNode] ....  here is a copy paste of the error: Error:(30, 48) type mismatch;
 found   : java.util.List[?0] where type ?0 <: org.htmlcleaner.TagNode
 required: scala.collection.immutable.List[_ <: org.htmlcleaner.TagNode]
  val articleLinksList = buildArticleLinksList(anchorNodes)
                                               ^

Comment: oh I see where I have gone wrong, nvm, I guess explaining it and re-reading it has its advantages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converted the Java List to a List for Scala and it has worked.

EDIT

Though I should include the import and the code, it was an easy fix once I read the error more carefully.

To fix it I basically imported JavaConverters like so:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
```

Then I converted the Java List to a Scala list like so:

```
val anchorNodes = bodyNode.getElementListByName("a", true).asScala.toList
```

The thing here is that `asScala` will map the Java List to a Buffer which is Scala's equivalent, so we can then convert that to a Scala List.